# Best way of making draggable element jump to cursor (and start drag) when mousedown on parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, draggable

I've got a home-made slider made from jQuery UI's `draggable()` function:

```
$("#petrolGauge .fuelBar .slider").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    axis: "x",
    drag:function(){
        updValues();
    },
    start:function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#666");
    },
    stop:function(){
        //checkForm();
        $(this).css("background-color","#AAA");
    }
});
```

This is for the following markup:

```
<div id="petrolGauge">
    <input id="endPet" name="endPet" type="hidden" value="0">
    How much fuel was left in the tank when you were finished? (Use the slider) <b>(~<span class="petLeft">0</span>%)</b>
    <span class="mandatory">*</span><br />
    <div class="fuelBar">
        <div title="Drag" class="slider"></div>
    </div>
```

This works a treat, when I click on the slider. But I'd like it so that when I click the fuel bar (the slider's parent) the slider not only starts dragging but also jumps to the cursor. I've achieved it by doing this:

```
$("#petrolGauge .fuelBar").on("mousedown",function(e){
    slider = $("#petrolGauge .fuelBar .slider");
    left = e.pageX-($(this).offset().left)-(slider.width()/2);
    updValues();
    slider.css("left",left).trigger(e);
});
```

Two problems with this:

Firstly, when clicking on the parent I get a couple of second's delay before the slider starts to drag? I've tried and tested this in Chrome and IE and both do it. Secondly if the cursor is less than half of the slider's width away from the edge of the parent, the slider will move to the outside of the parent. Wouldn't be hard to fix this with a couple of checking, but was wondering if there was another way? I'm suprised that `draggable()` doesn't have any parameters for this to be honest. I didn't want to use `slider()` if I could help it but if it's the only way, then it's the only way.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNUAL/) to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the delay is because you use `.trigger()` inside the `.on()` event which creates a big loop. As a result the loop slows down the moving process.

```
$("#petrolGauge .fuelBar").click(function (e) { // use click instead of mousedown
    slider = $("#petrolGauge .fuelBar .slider");
    left = e.pageX - ($(this).offset().left) - (slider.width() / 2);
    if(left > 570) { left = 570; } else if(left < 0) { left = 0; }
    // it looks like a draggable bug due to the manual position change, so use a small check
    slider.css("left", left); // change the position first
    updValues();              // then calculate and update the div 
    // no need to trigger the event a second time because it will loop until jQuery exceeds it's trigger limit.
});
```

Here's an updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/LNUAL/4/)

**Updated answer**

To make `.slider` move accordingly to the mouse movement when not directly dragged, bind  a `mousemove` event to the `mousedown` and unbind it when `mouseup`. Then in `.mousemove()`  you change the position of `.slider`.

```
var move = function (e) {
    left = e.pageX - ($('#petrolGauge .fuelBar').offset().left) - (slider.width() / 2);
    if (left > 570) {
        left = 570;
    } else if (left < 0) {
        left = 0;
    }
    slider.css("left", left);
    updValues();
};
var slider = $("#petrolGauge .fuelBar .slider");
$("#petrolGauge .fuelBar").mousedown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    left = e.pageX - ($(this).offset().left) - (slider.width() / 2);
    if (left > 570) {
        left = 570;
    } else if (left < 0) {
        left = 0;
    }
    slider.css("left", left)
    $(this).bind('mousemove', move);
    updValues();
}).mouseup(function () {
   $(this).unbind('mousemove');
});
```

Comment: Thanks you've explained the loop well, that had passed me by. I don't really want to use click because the idea was for it to be nice and smooth. I don't want the user to mousedown and then have to mouseup to then go on to adjust.

Comment: Yes.. exactly like that. Update your answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked, unfortunately I have no idea why `.slider` moves out of its `parent` but I'm guessing it's a bug generated by manually moving `.slider`. Anyway, that can be easily fixed with conditional statements.